# understanding why`execvp` works where `execv` fails

Tags: c, exec, execvp, execv

I was asked to implement a 'mini-shell' in C. I decided to work with `execv` and it didn't work, and when I changed it to `execvp` its working! Take a look of the code (the action is in `tokExec` function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>


void tokExec(char command[128])
{
    // 'strtok' may look innocent, but it modifies the string, so I want a copy of the original command.
    char tokString[128];
    // 'strlen' is the lenghth without the null terminator.
    strncpy(tokString,command,strlen(command)+1);


    char* tokPtr = NULL;
    char tok[] = " ";
    int narg = 0;
    tokPtr = strtok(tokString,tok);
    char *myargs[64];

    while(tokPtr != NULL)
    {
            printf("arg %d is: %s\n",narg,tokPtr);
            myargs[narg] = tokPtr;
            narg = narg + 1;
            tokPtr = strtok(NULL,tok);
    }
    printf("Total number of arguments: %d\n",narg);

    // add the final 'NULL' element.
    myargs[narg] = NULL;

    execvp(myargs[0],myargs);
    printf("error\n");
    exit(1);
}

void normal()
{
    char command[128];
    strcpy(command,"default\0");
    printf("myShellZ > ");
    gets(command);
    while(strcmp(command,"exit") != 0)
    {
            int status;
            pid_t pid;
            if( (pid = fork()) == 0 )
            {
                    tokExec(command);
            }
            wait(&status);
            printf("myShellz > ");
            gets(command);
    }
}

void debug()
{
    // TO DO ....
    int a = 3;
}

// switching between shell modes: normal or debug.
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if(argc == 1)
            normal();
    else if(strcmp("-debug",argv[1]))
            debug();
    else
            exit(1);

    exit(0);
}
```

If instead of the `execvp` in the end of `tokExec` I will use `execv`, if my input is only `ls` or `ps` etc `execv` is great, but if I add arguments to the input, for example: `ls -l myshell.c` or evev just `ls -l` or `ps aux` I got an `error` output.

The `man` barely refer to the differences between those functions, but it claims that:

> The  execv(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions provide an array of pointers to null-terminated strings that represent the argument list available to the new program.  The first
>          argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being 
>    executed.  The array of pointers must be terminated by a null pointer.

In conclusion, what's the difference betwwen `execv` and `execvp` that fixed my program in this case? I know that `execv` also works for bash commands since if I entered bash command without arguments it is working, and the signature of those two functions is identical. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Did you take a look at the return value of `execv` and `errno`?

Comment: Look further down in the documentation under the "Special semantics for execlp() and execvp()" , where it explains what execlp() does, that execve() would not do.

Comment: `execv` returns `int`. I tried `man errno` but I can't see any return value... anywhy what is have to do with the question? (makes my curious)

Comment: `perror` gave me `No such file or directory` which is explained in the answer, for `execv` you need to pass the whole path.

Comment: like `/bin/ls`?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: I've tried to concatenate multiple prefix to make it work with `execv`... for some reason none of them work. But I get the general idea... thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in the man page. If you read the section after the part you've quoted, it talks about the difference

> The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions
>   of  the
>          shell  in searching for an executable file if the specified filename does not
>          contain a slash (/) character.  The file is  sought  in  the  colon-separated
>          list  of  directory pathnames specified in the PATH environment variable.  If
>          this variable isn't defined, the path list defaults to the current  directory
>          followed  by  the  list  of directories returned by confstr(_CS_PATH).  (This
>          confstr(3) call typically returns the value "/bin:/usr/bin".)

Comment: alright, but why it doesn't work for `execv`? and why if I send only the command itself it is working even for `execv`?

Comment: Because `execv` doesn't do the above - it needs the full or relative path for the executable

Comment: @ZENir if you tell execvp() to run the "ls" command, it will search through your PATH, which is normally /bin/ /usr/bin/ /sbin/ and so on, and try to find the executable for the "ls" command and run it. If you tell execv() to run  the "ls" command, it will not look through the PATH, it will try to run the "ls" executable in the current directory - which doesn't exists unless you change your directory to /usr/bin/

Comment: @ChrisTurner So if I will concatenates `//bin/` to `args[0]` you claim that `execv` will work for all bash commands that are located in `bin` directory?

Comment: Sure, but you'd be better off using `execvp` so you don't have to re-implement the path searching functionality that your shell needs

Comment: Thanks a lot. btw I tried it and I got some weird result like `cannot access 'in/ls': No such file or directory` , do you have any guess why? (and I checked, no backslash by mistake or something...)

Comment: I'd guess you're not constructing the filename correctly, but without seeing your new code I wouldn't be able to say more. Ask a new question and someone should be able to spot the problem